# If string contains certain a word and ONLY that word

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to stop users searching with terms that give far too many results.

For example, I'd like users to be able to search for `"Big Island"` but not search for `"Island"`.

I tried this:

```
$array = array("island", "islands", "island's", "islet", "ilsets", "reef", "reefs", "shoal", "shoals");

if (0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $searchTerm)), $array)))
{
    echo "No results. The search term used was too general.";
    exit();
}
```

But that stops the search for any phrase with the stop words in it.

I guess I'm looking for something that goes like:

if the string contains this word or that word (and only one of those words!) stop what you're doing, else carry on...

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Limit the search results in some other way. Handicapping a users ability to use your search is a no-no.

Comment: So, only if all search terms occur in the stop words table, abort the search?

Comment: well, you are parsing the searchTerm into an array and searching on each word...  It's doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: @remyabel. The search engine searches a database of islands, reefs, emergent rocks and shoals etc. A search for "island" will attempt to fetch around 75% of the database (the search will stall at 50% I believe). Searching an island database for the word "island" is silly.

Comment: @Jack. Nope (if I'm understanding you correctly. I want to prevent a single word search for "island" or "islands" or "reef" etc. Those words used in conjunction with another word such as "South Minerva Reef" or "Norfolk Island" or "Rowley Shoals" are acceptable searches.

Comment: Fixed it by doing this first: "if (str_word_count($searchTerm) === 1) {...". Seems to work.

Comment: So what if I search for "reef island"?

Comment: @jack. I've think I've decided to abandoned the idea, as it's causing more headaches than I have the will to deal with. Each fix seems to create another potential problem.

Answer (score 0):

look at the strstr function it may help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: In what way would that help?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at searching after removing "stop words" which are words like "the" "and" etc. So remove the "stop words", then check if the search string is empty. Also make sure to add your other words to the stop words list.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

That way you can just say

```
if (in_array($searchterm,$array))
{
  // stop searching
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with regular expressions - here is a simple demo. You can of course generate the character groups (big|small) etc. from predefined arrays

```
$regex =  '/^(big|small)\s+(Island|islet|reef)$/';
    if ( 1 === preg_match($regex, 'big reef ') {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe let the user search and then present an "Related searches" à la Google...